# coap protocol get method use python

Tags: python, protocols, iot, coap

I'm trying to run an application with coap but I'm new. I am using the python coapthon3 library. But I want to get the payloads from the library using the encoding path. But I could not do this. My client code is as follows.
Thank you

```
from coapthon.client.helperclient import HelperClient

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5683
path = "encoding"
payload = 'text/plain'

client = HelperClient(server=(host, port))
response = client.get(path + 'application/xml' + '<value>"+str(payload)+"</value>')
client.stop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't concatenate all the stuff to the path.

Unfortunately **HelperClient#get** does not provide an ability to specify a payload though it is pretty legal according to CoAP spec.

So you need to create a request and fill all the needed fields, and to use **send_request** method.

I guess my snippet is not that pythonish so please bear with me.

```
from coapthon.client.helperclient import HelperClient
from coapthon.messages.request import Request
from coapthon import defines

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5683
path = "encoding"
payload = 'text/plain'

client = HelperClient(server=(host, port))

request = Request()
request.code = defines.Codes.GET.number
request.type = defines.Types['NON']
request.destination = (host, port)
request.uri_path = path
request.content_type = defines.Content_types["application/xml"]
request.payload = '<value>"+str(payload)+"</value>'
response = client.send_request(request)

client.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem with the code. when I run this code, the content_type turns as int. server-side resource.I couldn't add code to the comment. I'm sorry for that

Comment: Thanks, found the solution.